# Downloading JMeter Official Distribution as part of maven dependency (Not using maven plugi-in)

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, performance-testing

[Integrating JMeter as part of Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459394/integrating-jmeter-as-part-of-maven-project)

Extending the above question, is the possible to do the below steps through maven dependency itself, ideally we don't want to rely on the local installation of JMeter for running the test and don't want to use JMeter Maven Plug-in since we cannot specify which JMeter version we want to use to run the JMeter Script.

The answer mentioned is to use AntRunner but not sure how to do that through maven any pointer will be helpful

My scenario is to,

Download and Unzip the JMeter official distribution as maven dependency

Copy to target folder

JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("copied-target-folder/bin")

jmeter.run();

Comment: Actually you can set the JMeter version in the jmeter-maven-plugin: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/jmeter/mojo/ConfigureJMeterMojo.java#L59

Comment: You can also just have a look at the code in the jmeter-maven-plugin to see how that pulls down JMeter as a maven dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AntRunner and the following Ant tasks:

- [get](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)
- [unzip](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html)

Example:

```
<get src="url of jmeter"
     dest="${build.dir}/${zip}"
     usetimestamp="true" ignoreerrors="false"/>
<unzip dest="${build.dir}" src="${build.dir}/${zip}">
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help, I just need to add explicit proxy as part of my ant task to get it working behind my corporate firewall

Answer (score 0):

The [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) has a goal called [unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) which downloads a dependency (using maven coordinates) and unpacks it on a local directory. You can use that goal to download a given JMeter instance.

The syntax would go like this (not tested, you will have to adjust it):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>target/jmeter</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

That would fulfill your first step:

> Download and Unzip the JMeter official distribution as maven dependency

But I'm not sure there is a full zip version of JMeter published as a Maven dependency. You can unpack the *jar* files, maybe that's enough. Or maybe you just need to execute those *ant* steps.

You can execute any *ant* script (`build.xml`) using the antrunner plugin. You can find documentation and examples on the [Maven AntRun Plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).